# connecting title tag with database and make it auto refresh, just like in facebook title

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my web about title tag `<title></title>`. I want to connect it to database so that the value of my web title is from database, it worked. But another problem happened when I want to make my web title (not whole page) auto refresh. I have found the script from ajax but it doesn't really succeed just like in facebook title tag, just assume, I enter new data from another browser (ie, Opera, etc) and after I go back to my main browser (Firefox) the title tag does not change at all or does not auto refresh and change the value. I really need your help guys..!? This is the script that I've tried..

```
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: '{BASE_URL}/system/back-end/main.php',
  url: 'main.html',
  //data: {name: 'username', password: 'userpass'},
  success: function() { document.title = '$value';},
  dataType: 'text'
});
}, 1000);

function getXHR() { 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Chrome, Firefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  } 
  // IE6
  try { 
    // The latest stable version. It has the best security, performance, 
    // reliability, and W3C conformance. Ships with Vista, and available 
    // with other OS's via downloads and updates. 
    return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
  } catch (e) { 
    try { 
      // The fallback.
      return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch (e) { 
      alert('This browser is not AJAX enabled.'); 
      return null;
    } 
  } 
}
function setPageTitle(newValue) {
  document.title = '$value';
}

function messageCountAsPageTitle(msgCount) {
  // TODO: determine where 'another text in the page title' should be defined
  msgCount = '{PESAN_ENTRY} {BERKAS} {BERKAS}';
  setPageTitle('(' + msgCount + ') - another text in the page title');
}
<!--</tpl:tmpl>

function getMessageCount(callback) {
  var url = 'main.html?' + 'main.php?' + (new Date()).getTime(), // prevent caching
    xhr = getXHR();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.timeout = 2000; // Set the timeout to be less than the frequency we call this
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
setInterval(function() {getMessageCount(messageCountAsPageTitle);}, 3000);
```

please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (the top $.ajax() call) then you should only use this, not the bottom part. Make sure you include jQuery in the source of the HTML (google jQuery on how to do that)

You need to create a php file that returns the new title.

```
// script.php
echo 'My New Title';
exit();
```

Then use jQuery in your source to access the new title:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $.ajax({ 
     url: 'http://UrlToGetTheTitleFrom/script.php', 
     success: function(data) { document.title = data; }, 
     dataType: 'text' 
  }); 
}, 10000);
```

(Note: that 1000 in SetInterval EVERY SECOND - it's milliseconds. Pretty sure you don't want it hammering your server that quickly!)

Comment: i made new document, i was follow your script but nothing change like i echo in script.php, the title is still "Untitled Document"..

Comment: Well - check the response, check for error etc. in "success" add an alert(data). Also add a error conditon and put the error in alert. Just chek what you expect ot happen is hapenning. Documentation on jQuery AJAX calls is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: it still the same, when i change my database value from phpmyadmin, then i check my web the title is not automatically change..
i add..
..done : function() { alert("success")},
fail : function() { alert("error")}..
under dataType, but anything is still the same..
please help me..!?\

Comment: If you don't get an alert message, then the javascript is not being run. Check for errors, debug it. Press F12 in your borwser (Chrome or IE9) and go to "scripts". Check for errors, turn on debugging... Google for "Debug Javascript IE9 Developer Tools" or "Debug Javascript Chrome Developer Tools" for more